# StringContext and macros: a simple example

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm trying to achieve a `StringContext` extension which will allow me to write this:

```
val tz = zone"Europe/London" //tz is of type java.util.TimeZone
```

But with the added caveat that *it should fail to compile if the supplied time-zone is invalid* (assuming that can be determined at compile-time).

Here's a helper function:

```
def maybeTZ(s: String): Option[java.util.TimeZone] =
  java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs collectFirst { case id if id == s =>
    java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(id)
  }
```

I can create a non-macro implementation very easily:

```
scala> implicit class TZContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
 |   def zone(args: Any *) = {
 |     val s = sc.raw(args.toSeq : _ *)
 |     maybeTZ(s) getOrElse sys.error(s"Invalid zone: $s")
 |   }
 | }
```

Then:

```
scala> zone"UTC"
res1: java.util.TimeZone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,...
```

So far, so good. Except that this doesn't fail compilation if the timezone is nonsensical (e.g. `zone"foobar"`); the code falls over at runtime. I'd like to extend it to a macro but, despite reading the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html), I'm really struggling with the details (All of the details, to be precise.)

Can anyone help to get me started here? The all-singing, all-dancing solution should look to see if the `StringContext` defines any arguments and (if so), defer calculation until runtime, otherwise attempting to parse the zone at compile-time

---

*What have I tried?*

Well, macro defs appear to have to be in statically accessible objects. So:

```
package object oxbow {
  implicit class TZContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    def zone(args: Any *) = macro zoneImpl //zoneImpl cannot be in TZContext
  }

  def zoneImpl(c: reflect.macros.Context)
    (args: c.Expr[Any] *): c.Expr[java.util.TimeZone] = {
      import c.universe._
      //1. How can I access sc from here?

      /// ... if I could, would this be right?
      if (args.isEmpty) {
        val s = sc.raw()
        reify(maybeTZ(s) getOrElse sys.error(s"Not valid $s")) 
      }
      else {
        //Ok, now I'm stuck. What goes here?
      }
    }

}
```

---

Based on som-snytt's suggestion below, here's the latest attempt:

```
def zoneImpl(c: reflect.macros.Context)
           (args: c.Expr[Any] *): c.Expr[java.util.TimeZone] = {
  import c.universe._
  val z =
    c.prefix.tree match {
      case Apply(_, List(Apply(_, List(Literal(Constant(const: String)))))) => gsa.shared.datetime.XTimeZone.getTimeZone(const)
      case x => ??? //not sure what to put here
    }

  c.Expr[java.util.TimeZone](Literal(Constant(z))) //this compiles but doesn't work at the use-site
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             this is wrong. What should it be?
}
```

At the use-site, a valid `zone"UTC"` fails to compile with the error:

```
java.lang.Error: bad constant value: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null] of class class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
```

Presumably I should not have used a `Literal(Constant( .. ))` to enclose it. What should I have used?

---

Last example - based on Travis Brown's answer below

```
def zoneImpl(c: reflect.macros.Context)
         (args: c.Expr[Any] *): c.Expr[java.util.TimeZone] = {
  import c.universe._
  import java.util.TimeZone

  val tzExpr: c.Expr[String] = c.prefix.tree match {
    case Apply(_, Apply(_, List(tz @ Literal(Constant(s: String)))) :: Nil)
      if TimeZone.getAvailableIDs contains s => c.Expr(tz)
    case Apply(_, Apply(_, List(tz @ Literal(Constant(s: String)))) :: Nil) =>
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Invalid time zone! $s")
    case _ => ??? 
//            ^^^ What do I do here? I do not want to abort, I merely wish to 
//                "carry on as you were". I've tried ... 
//                    c.prefix.tree.asInstanceOf[c.Expr[String]]
//                ...but that does not work
  }
  c.universe.reify(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzExpr.splice))

}
```

Comment: Do you mind performing the `getTimeZone` lookup at run time, after confirming that the identifier is available at compile time? If so, you can use `reify(TimeZone.getTimeZone(c.literal(tz).splice))`, where `tz` is the string. Otherwise you're going to have a hard time smuggling the `TimeZone` out of the macro.

Comment: @TravisBrown Indeed, now I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. Could you be more specific? This solution is amenable but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to be putting this. What String tz?

Comment: I don't follow the comment about smuggling the time zone. I think an answer here could be really useful. It strikes me that what I'm doing is intro-level macro stuff and there's so little available in the way of explanation...

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: I've just posted an answer with a bit of explanation, and could flesh it out this evening if you have additional questions.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, a number of simple and not so-simple examples are available here: https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala#L53. That includes an example of StringContext and macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "song-and-dance" solution that handles interpolation of the timezone:

```
package object timezone {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def zoned(sc: StringContext) = new ZoneContext(sc)
}

package timezone {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context
  import java.util.TimeZone

  class ZoneContext(sc: StringContext) {

    def tz(args: Any*): TimeZone = macro TimeZoned.tzImpl

    // invoked if runtime interpolation is required
    def tz0(args: Any*): TimeZone = {
      val s = sc.s(args: _*)
      val z = TimeZoned maybeTZ s getOrElse (throw new RuntimeException(s"Bad timezone $s"))
      TimeZone getTimeZone z
    }
  }
  object TimeZoned {
    def maybeTZ(s: String): Option[String] =
      if (TimeZone.getAvailableIDs contains s) Some(s) else None

    def tzImpl(c: Context)(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[TimeZone] = {
      import c.universe._
      c.prefix.tree match {
        case Apply(_, List(Apply(_, List(tz @Literal(Constant(const: String)))))) =>
          maybeTZ(const) map (
            k => reify(TimeZone getTimeZone c.Expr[String](tz).splice)
          ) getOrElse c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Bad timezone $const")
        case x =>
          val rts = x.tpe.declaration(newTermName("tz0"))
          val rt = treeBuild.mkAttributedSelect(x, rts)
          c.Expr[TimeZone](Apply(rt, args.map(_.tree).toList))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
package tztest 

import timezone._

object Test extends App {

  val delta = 8
  //Console println tz"etc/GMT+$delta"  //java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad timezone etc/GMT+8
  Console println tz"Etc/GMT+$delta"
  Console println tz"US/Hawaii"
  //Console println tz"US/Nowayi"     //error: Bad timezone US/Nowayi
}
```

Comment: How do I "return what I received"?

Comment: I've tried tons of stuff here, trying to reify/splice my time zone (into what expression?), or figure out what sort of expression it is (as it's not a `Literal(Constant(..))`, to no avail

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This will have the same issue, though. In your case, a String "funk?" is a literal constant. But in my case, my time zone is not. I want to build the expression which is the lookup. Unfortunately one seems to need to know one's DefDef from ones ValDef to have any kind of a clue as to how to create the expression tree. As you imply, the documentation is sparse on such detail.

Comment: I can't get this to compile - the call to `TermName` is not found

Comment: Sorry about that -- I am a bleeding-edge deprecationist.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you can't smuggle a compile-time instance of `TimeZone` into the code generated by your macro. You can, however, slip a string literal through, so you can generate code that will *construct* the `TimeZone` you want at run time, while still checking at compile time to make sure the identifier is available.

The following is a complete working example:

```
object TimeZoneLiterals {
  import java.util.TimeZone
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  implicit class TZContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    def zone() = macro zoneImpl
  }

  def zoneImpl(c: reflect.macros.Context)() = {
    import c.universe._

    val tzExpr = c.prefix.tree match {
      case Apply(_, Apply(_, List(tz @ Literal(Constant(s: String)))) :: Nil)
        if TimeZone.getAvailableIDs contains s => c.Expr(tz)
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid time zone!")
    }

    reify(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzExpr.splice))
  }
}
```

The argument to `reify` will be the body of the generated method—literally, not after any kind of evaluation, except that the `tzExpr.slice` bit will be replaced by the compile-time string literal (if, of course, you've found it in the list of available identifiers—otherwise you get a compile-time error).

Comment: +1 for the tidy unapply. Later I'll figure out what the Nil adds to the match (I'll have to count the parens first). This isn't the vaudeville version, all-singing, etc. I wonder if it handles the procrastinator's timezone, "UTC$DelayedInit".

Comment: Yes, I knew (sort of) that I was trying to *reify* the `TimeZone.getTimeZone` call but didn't know how. Thanks loads for the help!

Comment: OK, so this works in the REPL. It works in a standalone project. But it does not work in the project where I want to put the code (it's in a package `oxbow.scala`). I get a compilation error which says **"object collection is not a member of package oxbow.scala"**. Any ideas?

Comment: So, I moved the impl into a sub-package and this compiles. But now I have an extra problem - I want this to compile: `val z = "UTC; zone"$z"` (it can remain unchecked if necessary). Evidently the expression "$z" is not a literal constant. I've amended my question with your suggestions but have one last question - how do I avoid making the check in the case where the expression is not a literal constant?

Comment: I think you could use som-snytt's approach from his answer above (the pattern match clause starting with `case x =>`).

Comment: Hi Eugene - yes, I've done this and it is working a treat! Thanks to both Travis and som-snytt's help here. As an aside, I think this is a useful case study for `scalamacros.org`

Comment: @oxbow_lakes `package oxbow.scala` you are so brave!  I agree more macro examples would be fruitful.