# Macro access to members of object where macro is defined

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Say I have a trait `Foo` that I instantiate with an initial value `i`

```
val foo = new Foo(6) // class Foo(i: Int)
```

and I later call a `secondMethod` that in turn calls `myMacro`

```
foo.secondMethod(7) // def secondMethod(j: Int) = macro myMacro
```

then, how can `myMacro` find the initial value of `i` (6)?

I didn't succeed with normal compilation reflection using `c.prefix`, `c.eval(...)` etc but instead found a 2-project solution:

Project B:

```
object CompilationB {
    def resultB(x: Int, y: Int) = macro resultB_impl
    def resultB_impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int], y: c.Expr[Int]) =
      c.universe.reify(x.splice * y.splice)
}
```

Project A (depends on project B):

```
trait Foo {
  val i: Int

  // Pass through `i` to compilation B:
  def apply(y: Int) = CompilationB.resultB(i, y)
}

object CompilationA {
  def makeFoo(x: Int): Foo = macro makeFoo_impl
  def makeFoo_impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Foo] =
    c.universe.reify(new Foo {val i = x.splice})
}
```

We can create a `Foo` and set the `i` value either with normal instantiation or with a macro like `makeFoo`. The second approach allows us to customize a `Foo` at compile time in the first compilation and then in the second compilation further customize its response to input (`i` in this case)! In some way we get "meta-meta" capabilities (or "pataphysic"-capabilities ;-)

Normally we would need to have foo in scope to introspect `i` (with for instance c.eval(...)). But by saving the `i` value inside the `Foo` object we can access it anytime and we could instantiate `Foo` anywhere:

```
object Test extends App {
  import CompilationA._

  // Normal instantiation
  val foo1 = new Foo {val i = 7}
  val r1   = foo1(6)

  // Macro instantiation
  val foo2 = makeFoo(7)
  val r2   = foo2(6)

  // "Curried" invocation
  val r3 = makeFoo(6)(7)

  println(s"Result 1 2 3: $r1 $r2 $r3")
  assert((r1, r2, r3) ==(42, 42, 42))
}
```

**My question**

Can I find `i` inside my example macros without this double compilation hackery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be easy to access members of `Foo` inside the macro without having to resort to double compilation. Here is how our example macro can access the value of `i`:

```
    val i = c.Expr[Int](Select(c.prefix.tree, TermName("i")))
    reify(i.splice * j.splice)
```

To be precise, `i` here is actually an `Expr` that we can splice and work with inside the reify *as a* number value.

So yes, it is possible inside a macro (`process`) to access members (`i`) of the object (`Foo`) where the macro is defined (`Foo`) within a single compilation (by "defined" I mean where I use the `macro` keyword):

```
object compilation {
  def makeFoo(x: Int): Foo = macro makeFoo_impl
  def makeFoo_impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Foo] =
    c.universe.reify(new Foo {val i = x.splice})

  def process(c: Context)(j: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Int] = {
    import c.universe._
    // Foo.i accessed inside macro
    val i = c.Expr[Int](Select(c.prefix.tree, TermName("i")))
    reify(i.splice * j.splice)
  }
}

trait Foo {
  val i: Int
  def apply(j: Int) = macro compilation.process
}

object Test extends App {
  import compilation._

  val foo1 = new Foo {val i = 6}
  Console println foo1(7) // 42

  val foo2 = makeFoo(6)
  Console println foo2(7) // 42

  Console println makeFoo(6)(7) // 42
}
```

I owe this solution to a question/answer by Francesco Bellomi/Eugene Burmako on the Scala-user list that I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/val%2420b%2420%243D%2420%22foo%22%243B%2420def%2420a%2420%243D%2420macro%2420impl%2420/scala-user/XcFfby69eVk/3NyOdso5xo0J).

As a side note, we don't necessarily need to use `c.eval(...)` to get the *actual value* from an `Expr` of some untyped [correct to say it like that?] `Tree`. In most cases we should be fine getting the value *wrapped in an `Expr`* since we can use that *as* a value by splicing it inside a reify and do all our calculations with the (splice-)value there!

Comment: Another example with prefix http://stackoverflow.com/a/17028600/1296806 and see the end of this answer for self-answering: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12486993/1296806

Comment: I actually studied the other answer you refer too. But I didn't make the mental leap from the Tree deconstruction-construction in that example to using prefix as basis for Tree construction. Well I tried several combinations, but not the `Select(c.prefix.tree, TermName("i"))` one.